# How do you update/add to SQL tables with bash commands?

Tags: mysql, bash, snmp

Need to add SNMP information to a SQL database and update it on a regular schedule. SNMP info can be queried from bash commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash commands to write insert statements to a file, then pipe the file into the mysql program.

Say you have a file that looks like this:

```
key1,1.0
key2,1.4
key3,1.9
key4,2.0
key5,3.5
```

you can pipe it into a bash script that looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read key, value; do
    echo "insert into sometable(key, value) values('$key' $value);"
done >/tmp/inserts.sql

mysql </tmp/inserts.sql >/tmp/inserts.out
```

If your data comes from somewhere else then same principle, just generate SQL commands into a file and pipe them into mysql.

This strategy isn't as kludgy as it might seem at first.  MySQL's own mysqldump backup utility dumps the database to a file in the form of SQL statements.